# How to check how many times a word appears in a txt file in php?

Tags: php, logfile

How can you check how many times a word occurs in a txt/log file?

For example:

110.90.252.35 -- [2007-05-01 10:10:55] "GET articles/learn_PHP_basics HTTP/1.0" 200 11178 "MSIE 7.0"

23.18.147.37 -- [2007-05-01 10:54:33] "GET about/contact.php HTTP/1.0" 200 4326 "Mozilla/4.0"

250.69.170.251 -- [2007-05-01 11:38:11] "GET articles/not/a/page HTTP/1.0" 404 0 "Mozilla/4.0"

Three statements taken from the log file, I'm trying to see how many times the word 'articles' appears in this file. I've tried using an array and then counting how many times that it appears but it hasn't worked out so far. So is there any other way.

My code:

```
enter code here

$mayFile = "C:\Users\Elsa\Desktop\TMA\may.log";
$myfile = fopen("may.log", "r");

$lines = count(file("may.log"));
echo "There are $lines lines";

while(!feof($myfile)) {
     $getFile = fgets($myfile);
     $parts = explode(" ",$getFile);
     $frequency = array_count_values($parts);
     print_r($parts);
     $items = array_count_values($parts);
   }




   fclose($myfile);
   fclose($myfile1);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done much easier:

```
$filename = "C:\Users\Elsa\Desktop\TMA\may.log";
$searchFor = "articles";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($filename);
$count = substr_count($fileContent, $searchFor);
echo "'$filename' contains '$searchFor' $count times";
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be a php function for that:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php